# passing parameter in make file

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am using visual code on mac for python and very new to make file environment.
I have a make file command as below,

```
   mkdir mydir
   zip mydir/test test1111/mypython.py
```

How should I parameterize test1111? Thanks.

Comment: it's actually pretty large, i just put few lines here.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you want to achieve. Do you want to zip many files (`*/mypython.pl`) into the same archive? Or zip many files, each into their own archive? Or create a makefile where `test1111` can be passed to it on the command line? Or something else?

Answer (score 0):

```
ZIP = zip

test_CONTENT = \
    test1111/mypython.py

mydir/test.zip: ${test_CONTENT}
    @mkdir -p ${@D}
    ${ZIP} $@ $^
```